# CSS - Change only the DIV font color inside a DIV on hover

Tags: html, css

I have this DIV:

```html
<div class="menu">
    <label id="label1">label</label>
    <div id="content">
        content
    </div>
    <a href="" id="link>link</a>
</div>
```

When I hover the DIV, I only want to change the DIV's font color, not the label's and not the link's.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try adding color value to the label and link to override the hover

Comment: Exactly. I dont quite understand which div you are talking about?

Comment: the div i wwanted to change was the div id="content"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m8YnG/).

**CSS:**

```
.menu:hover #content {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want to add something like this to your css?

```
div.menu:hover div#content {
    color: red; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also if you will have more divs (with other #id) inside the menu and you want that text to respond to the hover you could use:

```
.menu:hover .menu div {
    color: red;
}
```